# MassTransit with SQS/SNS. Messages not publishing to SQS queues

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

I am trying to subscribe a SNS topic to SQS queue using the masstransit configuration mentioned in their docs. The messages are published but do not appear in the SQS queues. SQS queue name: "test", SNS Topic name: "kbbico-manual-to-replace".

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                /*Configuring a receive endpoint will use the message topology to create and subscribe SNS topics to SQS queues so that 
                 * published messages will be delivered to the receive endpoint queue*/
                x.AddConsumer<OfferConsumer>();
                x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("ca-central-1", h =>
                    {
                        //h.Config(AmazonSQSConfig);
                        //h.Config(AmazonSnsConfig);                     
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test", e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<OfferConsumer>(context);
                        // disable the default topic binding
                        //e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

                        //Topic subscibed to a recieve endpoint
                        e.Subscribe("kbbico-manual-to-replace", s =>
                        {
                            // set topic attributes
                            s.TopicAttributes["DisplayName"] = "Public Event Topic";
                            s.TopicSubscriptionAttributes["some-subscription-attribute"] = "some-attribute-value";
                            s.TopicTags.Add("environment", "development");
                        });
                    });
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });


            });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configure a consumer, so the messages are likely being moved to the *_skipped* queue (or maybe the SQS DLQ).

Also, the `cfg.ConfigureEndpoints()` within the host configuration does not belong there at all. It should come at the very end of the bus configuration.

Comment: Added the consumer and moving the cfg.ConfigureEndpoints() to the very end didn't helped either. I tried adding h.config(amazonsqsconfig) as well but no luck. @ChrisPatterson

Comment: Enable debug logging to see what's being created on SQS/SNS. Honestly, it works for everyone but you.

Comment: Also, [check permissions](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/amazonsqs.html), make sure you're able to create topics, queues, subscriptions, etc. The list of required permissions are at the bottom of that link.

Comment: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:767848882003:undefined/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "topic-subscription-arn:aws:sns:ca-central-1:767848882003:kbbico-manual-to-replace",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:767848882003:test",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:ca-central-1:767848882003:kbbico-manual-to-replace"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Above is the access policy for the SQS queue "test" which I am using to publish messages

Comment: Checked the permissions for SNS as well and looks all good

Comment: Like I said, logging.